# How can I change a Number-type column to a Date-type in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake and have a number-type column with a YYYYMM format (for example, a row with 202207 = July 2022).

I would like to convert this into a date format, preferably the same formatting as YYYYMM.

I have tried to write various queries like:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(report_month)
FROM table

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(report_month)
FROM table
```

But they don’t work. I am new to Snowflake, so is changing a numbers-type column to a Date-type (YYYYMM) even possible?

I hope this makes sense, and thank you for the help!

Comment: what will be the DD of the date type column?

Comment: Hi Nikhil, there is no DD in the Number-type column. I guess we can just treat it as 01, but if it’s possible to omit it, I think that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string of YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD Date format in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144683/convert-string-of-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
select to_date('201207', 'YYYYMM');
```

Comment: But converts always to first day of the month!!

Comment: A date type must have a year, month, and day of the month.

Comment: @GregPavlik be default it is 1st of the month

Comment: please ignore my comment. I just noticed that your comment was clarifying your answer. I mistakenly thought it was from the original poster.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, is it possible to use the TO_DATE function on an entire column instead of a specific number?

Comment: @Michael yes if all the values in the columns are in that format!!

Comment: @Michael use it and give it a green tick!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT
   YEAR(PERIOD)||MONTH(PERIOD)
FROM
   (SELECT
      DATE(TO_DATE(report_month, 'YYYYMM') PERIOD
   FROM
      table)
```

Comment: Hi Hilman, I tried that and unfortunately it doesn’t work. The error message says “Unexpected AS”

Comment: @Michael have you tried removing the 'AS'? I'm not really familiar with Snowflake, you can just alias the DATE(TO_DATE(report_month, 'YYYYMM') then use it to concat the year and month

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).